# How to write a function to find all rows where value in a column is null when values in dependent columns are not null

Tags: python, pandas

```py
def check_correlated_column_values(df,column,dependent_column_list):
        result = df.loc[(df[column].isnull()) & (pd.notnull(df[dependent_column_list[0]])) & (pd.notnull(df[dependent_column_list[1]])) & (pd.notnull(df[dependent_column_list[2]]))]
        return (result)
```

This `dependent_column_list` is dynamic and can change for a particular column.

Example: A dataframe has 3 columns, ManagerName, ManagerPhone and ManagerEmail, I want to write a generic function that finds all rows where ManagerName is null but ManagerPhone and ManagerEmail column values are NOT NULLs.

In the above function context, `column='ManagerName'`, `dependent_column_list=['ManagerPhone', ManagerEmail']`. Above function is working only when there are 3 columns in dependent list, want to make it generic so that it can handle any number of dynamic changes in that list.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with any loop system, as Bruno Mello answered.

But you can do it with the function `any()` and `all()`.

> `All()` - Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if
>   the iterable is empty). [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

```
pd.notnull(df[dependent_column_list])
```

This will create a dataframe with only Boolean data. So, you don't have to declare the columns. It makes the code general.

But **attention** to the `axis=1` inside de parentheses. This will synthesize the rows, instead the column (default).

```
def check_correlated_column_values(df,column,dependent_column_list):
        result = df.loc[(df[column].isnull()) & (pd.notnull(df[dependent_column_list]).all(axis=1))]
        return (result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this response worked perfectly fine, selecting this as answer (for it being one-liner) for current use-case. Bruno's response also worked fine. Thanks so much guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop:

```
def check_correlated_column_values(df,column,dependent_column_list):
        mask = (df[column].isnull())
        for col in dependent_column_list:
            mask = mask & (pd.notnull(df[col]))

        result = df.loc[mask]
        return (result)
```